# Slow Performance in Slate Edit mode

Tags: google-chrome, palantir-foundry, slate

we are developing a slate application with many widgets. The development now gets very slow as the application is not reacting or barely reacting whenever we are in the edit mode. We have many Dialogs that will open when a specific element is clicked but most of the time they are not visible.

Are there any best practices in terms of:

- Which Browser to use ?
- How to structure widgets for better perfromance ?
- How many widgets and visualizations should i use ?
- Any other ideas to boost performance ?

As current develpment is barely possible.

Virtual Client with:

- RAM 16GB
- AMD EPYC™ 7742 (2.25 GHz *2 )

Thank you

I tried different browsers and for different users with same results.